# Base and Inheritance class names/prefixes

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a main class such as the following ( with extending class called `Keys` )

```
public class Engine : Keys, IEngine, IDisposable
{
   private readonly Network _network;
   public Engine(bool useMainNet = false) : base(useMainNet)
   {
      _network = useMainNet ? Network.Main : Network.TestNet;
   }

   public Network GetCurrentNetwork() => _network;
```

Where the `Keys` class has functions like `GenerateKeys()` as following

```
public class Keys : IDisposable, IKeys
{
  public Keys(bool useMainNet = false)
  {
      _network = useMainNet ? Network.Main : Network.TestNet;
  }
  public string GenerateKeys()
  {
      return "KEY_GEN";
  }
}
```

The problem is I can call the method as follows

```
 using (Engine engine = new(true))
 {     
      engine.GenerateKeys();
 }
```

It works fine, but what I want is the following

```
using (Engine engine = new(true))
{     
    engine.Keys.GenerateKeys();
    // OR engine.Keys().GenerateKeys();
}
```

So I want the `Main_Method.Sub_Method.Function`, It makes more sense this way, Is it possible?

Comment: But why do you want to to this?

Comment: It sounds like you want composition instead of inheritance.

Comment: thanks for the comments guys, cheers, yep I mixed up the composition with inheritance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you are probably mixing the principles of compositions and inheritance

Try this:

```cs
public class Engine : IEngine, IDisposable
{
   private readonly Network _network;
   public Engine(bool useMainNet = false) : base(useMainNet)
   {
      _network = useMainNet ? Network.Main : Network.TestNet;
   }

   public Network GetCurrentNetwork() => _network;

   // by property
   public Keys Keys => new Keys();

   // by method (with parameters)
   public Keys Keys(bool useMainNet = false) => new Keys(useMainNet);

   ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, yes I needed composition as i don't need backend class object until and unless it is required